# Unit test for Race condition or concurrent issue

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have faced couple of issues in our production org

**Issue 1:**
there are two or more identical calls from external system arrived in SF at very short period of time. Both of them trying to insert data which is the same.

**possible solution**: 1. add Time to Live flag on the parent\shared object to check
2. add external id to make sure the data is unique to prevent

**Issue 2:** two users do similar things and trigger the same delete event, however the delete can successfully happen to only one of them

**possible solution**: try catch the error and swallow it.

**Questions**

1. are these possible fix will actually fix the issue
2. is it possible to reproduce the issue in unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing-wise, you're a bit stuck. I've sometimes done crazy things where I've used `@TestVisible` and/or `if(Test.isRunningTest())` to make tests where the code behaves in the way I think it does during a race condition. But you can't directly test the parallel execution.

For your two specific issues, it depends a bit on the larger requirements. If the external system tries to insert duplicates, your system could either decide to throw one of them back as an error, or say they both succeeded but only create one.

If you're happy to throw back an error then use either: duplicate matching rules; a field which is set to be unique; or a trigger which checks for duplicates on more complex criteria.

If you want to allow the external system to think it has succeeded, but only create one proper record in SF, then you will probably be best using some sort of staging object. Instead of directly inserting the record you want to keep, the external system inserts something else (maybe a Platform Event? Or a custom object?), then you turn that into the record you actually want to keep. Platform Events are perfect for this.

For the delete scenario, I'd just do the delete with `allOrNone=false` and ignore any errors where the record has already been deleted.

Comment: Hi Aidan, due to the size of the table, we cannt do a unique field or triggers easliy. We ends up with a TTL flag\lock, which will be checked as the first thing of API calls.

Answer (score 0):

For your issues:
Why not use a Queueable interface to handle the processes. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm
you can set your queueable process to do validations before doing update/delete

For your question about unit test, I don't believe it is possible to reproduce concurrency issue in a unit test.

Comment: You mean create a queueable job when i receive the API call, move all the logical into the queueable job? what's the limits of doing this. Thanks

Comment: Maximum number of Apex jobs added to the queue with System.enqueueJob - 50
You shouldn't reach that limit as long as you're adding them one at a time.